# SignalR - Client receives duplicated messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

I have a problem with receiving duplicated messages on Client side.

Below is server side (ASP.NET CORE) subscribtion: So in **AddClientSubscribtion** method I am checking in memory clientList if passed connectionId has been already subscribed - if yes this method return **false**. So assigning to a group is established by fixtureId - it means that group name = fixtureId.

```
public async Task SubscribeFixtureActions(string fixtureId)
{
      var isAdded = _broadcastService.AddClientSubscribtion(Context.ConnectionId, SocketMessageType.NewFixtureAction);

      if (isAdded)
      {
          await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, fixtureId);
      }
}
```

Here you can find sending message method for particular group:

```
public void SendByMatchHub(string fixtureId, string message, string messageType)
{
    _matchHubContext.Clients.Group(fixtureId).SendAsync(messageType, message);
}
```

This is method written in AngularJS client side for receiving message:

```
  this._ws.hubConnection.on(MatchActionWSEvent.RECEIVED_NEW_ACTIONS, receivedData => {
  try {
    const receivedObject = JSON.parse(receivedData);
    this._store.dispatch(receivedNewActions(receivedObject));
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log('RECEIVED_NEW_ACTIONS error', err)
  }
})
```

Client is calling **SubscribeFixtureActions** every time when user opens '**fixture details**' page. Fixture details can be opened from '**fixture list**' page so I can step to "**fixture details**' and then bo gack to '**fixture list**' and step again to '**fixture details**' so in this scenario client will call **SubscribeFixtureActions** two times.

So my problem is that this method is calling as many times as client subscribe to this group.
But I do not understand why? Because in the server method **SubscribeFixtureActions** you can see that code is checking if client is already added and Groups.AddToGroupAsync is called only if ConnectionId has not been added earlier.

```
 this._ws.hubConnection.on(MatchActionWSEvent.RECEIVED_NEW_ACTIONS, receivedData => {
```

When I debugging I can see that the group has only 1 member but client "on" function is called as many time as client invoke **subscribeFixtureActions** method

I am not sure what I am doing wrong because from server side perspective I am sure that adding to group is executed only one time!

Comment: Same problem here. Worse still, occasionally, one group gets messages meant for a different group!